# tr not working inside function

Tags: bash, tr

I am new to trying to write bash functions, so maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I execute:

```
myfile=test.txt
cat $myfile 2>&1 | tee "cat_$(echo "$myfile" | tr . _)_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S).txt"
```

it saves a file that starts with `cat_test_txt_`

But when I save this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
catfile () {
  cat $1 2>&1 | tee "cat_$(echo "$1" | tr . _)_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S).txt";
}
```

Then execute:

```
catfile test.txt
```

It saves a file that starts with `cat_test.txt_`

Does anyone know why the "." is not being replaced by "_"?

Comment: Works for me. Check that you're running that actual function and not e.g. some earlier version that worked differently. Remember that modifying `.bashrc` doesn't affect the functions set in a running shell.

Comment: I would do the process substitutions into local variables in the function. Maybe it should not make any difference, but it would be far easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: @ilkkachu, you must be right. When I exited that shell and started a new shell, it is now working :/

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, thanks, those are great tips. I'll definitely do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know and I can't reproduce.

You can do `typeset -f catfile` to check that your function is defined as you think it is, or run `(set -o xtrace; catfile test.txt)` to see what it's actually doing.

However here, if using `bash`, I'd rather write it:

```
catfile () {
  local file
  printf -v file 'cat_%s_%(%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S)T.txt' "${1//./_}" -1
  <"$1" tee -- "$file"
}
```

Using `bash`'s builtin `printf` for formatting and timestamp expansion and the ksh93-style `${param//pattern/replacement}` [parameter expansion operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to do the `.` -> `_` substitution.

Or the `zsh` equivalent:

```
catfile() <$1 >&1 > cat_${1//./_}_${(%):-%D{%Y_%m_%d_%Y%M%S}}.txt
```

Here using `zsh`'s internal `tee` when output is redirected more than once and prompt expansion (here enabled upon parameter expansion using the `%` parameter expansion flag) to generate the timestamp.

Some (unrelated) problems with your approach:

- you're using `echo` which can't be used for arbitrary data
- You forgot the quotes around `$1`.
- You forgot `--` before `$1` to delimit options
- UUOC.

Comment: Yeah, I was only using `cat` to test my understanding of functions. The goal was to make a function called `logpy` which would run `python` on `$1`, and save stdout and stderr to a log file with a name that included the name of the script ran and a timestamp.

Comment: What is(are) the term(s) I should look up to learn more about the syntax `${1//./_}`?  I tried "bash curly braces substitution" but I'm not finding any sources that show that syntax.

Comment: @Joe, that's one of many parameter expansion operators. `info bash 'parameter expansion'` should get you there.